# why session state not fire after 2 minute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

I work on blazor server side . I face issue session state not redirect to login after 2 minutes .

so I need when user leave current page after 2 minutes then redirect to login page

I applied code but my code not working why this code not working I don't know why not work .

what I try

1- I create JS `checksessiontimeout` file include redirect login after 2 minutes

```
function checkSessionTimeout(currentUrl) {
    var sessionTimeout = 2 * 60 * 1000; // 2 minutes in milliseconds
    var lastActivity = new Date(Date.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("LastActivity"))); // get the last activity time from the client-side session

    if (new Date() - lastActivity > sessionTimeout) {
        sessionStorage.clear(); // clear the session storage
        window.location.href = '/login?returnUrl=' + encodeURIComponent(currentUrl); // redirect to login page with return URL
    }
    else {
        setTimeout(function () { checkSessionTimeout(currentUrl); }, 1000); // check again in 1 second
    }
}

checkSessionTimeout(window.location.href);
```

2-on _host file I added JS file on body section

```
<script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
<script src="~/assets/js/checksessiontimeout.js"></script>
```

3-on load of blazor page I set session

```
  protected override void OnInitialized()
{
        JS.InvokeVoidAsync("sessionStorage.setItem", "LastActivity", DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString());
        //Session.SetInt32("LastActivity", (int)DateTime.Now.Ticks * -1);
}
```

4-after component load i run this code below :

```
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        
         if (firstRender)
        {
            await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("checkSessionTimeout", navigationManager.Uri);
        }

    }
```

so my issue why page not redirect to login after 2 minutes ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue by changing `setitem` for  variable `LastActivity` intial value

From:

```
JS.InvokeVoidAsync("sessionStorage.setItem", "LastActivity", DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString());
```

To:

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
string nowString = now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss");
JS.InvokeVoidAsync("sessionStorage.setItem", "LastActivity", now);
```

And my issue solved

And mainly raison that page not redirect to login after 2 minutes is not set

Session data correctly and by using

`console.log` it give me invalid date

So after make changing redirect to login page done success